# What is the benefit to reference a method in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

I found code on GitHub that is similar to my `ExampleClass`, but I don't understand the benefit of using `getx = calcualte_x`. I feel like it is somewhat close to `@property`, but it is not obviously.

what is the benefit of that line and why not just use `class-instance.calcualte_x(add)` instead of `class-instance.getx(add)`

```
class ExampleClass():
    def __init__(self, x_val):
        self.x = x_val

    def calcualte_x(self, add):
        x = self.x + add

    getx = calcualte_x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be an alias - for ease of use or for backward compatibility for example.

Comment: hello Benjamin. could you specify the Advantage in case of "backward compatibility"

Comment: If your code is used by others and you want to not break their code you have to modify your code without changing your API. More about backward compatibility you can read here: [Backward compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility).